# Properly configuring PySpark and Anaconda3 on Linux

Tags: linux, hadoop, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Here are the steps I have taken so far:

1. I installed Anaconda3 and everything included on the directory `$HOME/anaconda3/bin`.
2. I cd'ed into `$HOME/anaconda3/bin` and ran the command `./conda install -c conda-forge pyspark`. It was successful.
3. I didn't do anything else. More specifically, there are no variables set in my `.bashrc`

Here are some important details:

- I am on a distributed cluster running Hadoop, so there might be other directories outside of my home folder that I have yet to discover but I might need. I also don't have admin access.
- Jupyter notebook runs just fine.

Here is my goal:

**Goal.** To do something along the lines of adding variables or configuring some files so that I can run pyspark on Jupyter Notebook.

What are other steps I need to do after Step 3 in order to achieve this goal?

Comment: If you want to use modules installed in Anaconda within Jupyter notebook, then your best bet is to run Jupyter itself on your Anaconda.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: I'm not sufficiently familiar with Jupyter to say for sure.  It might be as simple as ensuring that Anaconda's bin/ directory is at the beginning of your path.  It might require installing your own copy of Jupyter inside your Anaconda.  There are other possibilities.

Comment: Look into Apache Toree if you want Jupyter with Spark. Otherwise, you can switch to Apache Zeppelin for a pre-built Spark notebook environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have installed pyspark with `conda`, and as you say Jupyter notebook runs fine (presumably for the same Anaconda distribution), there are no further steps required - you should be able to open a new notebook and `import pyspark`.

Notice though that installing pyspark that way (i.e. with `pip` or `conda`) gives only limited functionality; from the package [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyspark):

> The Python packaging for Spark is not intended to replace all of the
>   other use cases. This Python packaged version of Spark is suitable for
>   interacting with an existing cluster (be it Spark standalone, YARN, or
>   Mesos) - but does not contain the tools required to setup your own
>   standalone Spark cluster. You can download the full version of Spark
>   from the Apache Spark downloads page.

Installing pyspark with `pip` or `conda` is a relatively recent [add-on](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1267), aimed at the cases described in the docs above. I don't know what limitations you may face (have never tried it) but if you need the full functionality, you should download the full Spark distribution (of which pyspark is an integral part).